# vuex actions - unable to dispatch payload to a consequetive actions from one another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to call one action from another within the same action.js file. I've linked those up and have achieved this, but the problem is that the first action has to pass a payload to the second.

However, when I do pass the payload:

```
          store.dispatch('live-chat-queue/test', {
            input: 'test input'
        })
```

Instead of having access to it in the second action:

```
    test(payload) {
    console.log('This does not work..', payload)
},
```

What ends up happening is I get the store returned, instead of the payload:

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAxXn.png)

I have looked through ought the documentation and could not find the answer why this is returning the store, instead of the payload itself.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why taking the trouble of taking three images, cropping, uploading, wasting silica, when you've could easily just copy/paste the code :) Please read [ask]

Comment: actions receive store object as first argument, and payload as second

Comment: @Serg, when called with store.dispatch, the first argument is the payload, if you pass a second, that's the options object to the first parameter - or so it would seem from what I am seeing.

Comment: @StevenStephonson i don't think so, i mean, im looking at the docs right now, it says `test(context, payload) {}`, and this is exactly what you see in your console.log.

Comment: @Serg , I got what you are saying! Thanks, that solved it - it seems I have misunderstood the docs. If you want to type your answer below, I will be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @StevenStephonson let's earn some points at the end of 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states, actions receive store object as first argument and payload as second:

```js
test(context, payload) {
  console.log(payload) // works like expected
}
```